# gcc-4.0 on mac and xcode 4 already installed

Tags: python, gcc

I need to install a library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/fable/files/fabio/0.0.8/) on my mac but I keep getting the following message:

```
compile options: '-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include - I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c'
gcc-4.0: src/ccp4_pack.c
sh: gcc-4.0: command not found
```

I have Xcode 4 installed but I don't have any gcc file in /usr/bin/. But I have something in /Developer/usr/bin/ named gcc which saying this when I say open gcc:

```
/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 ; exit;
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files
logout
```

I am a bit lost in this installation. I have the feeling that I have gcc in another directory that the one needed and in another version (4.2 instead of 4.0). Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I have xcode4 on a mac 1.7.3 and I can't use RVM ton install rubies because it say C ompilter (gcc and others) is missing

Answer (score 1):

```
sh: gcc-4.0: command not found
```

Your shell can't find an executable named 'gcc-4.0'. You might alias that or create a symlink temporarily while you're installing the library.

Answer (score 0):

Entering this command in sudo su mode : `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i686"` solve this problem even if I don't exactly know why...!